# Regular expression to match until '{' character?

Tags: regex, sed

Is it possible to create a regular expression for use with sed, to match everything from (and including):

```
main(argc, argv)
```

up to (but not including) the next '{' character?

I'm not sure how to match this across multiple lines.

Expected input:

```
blah

main(argc, argv)
a
b
c
{
```

Expected match:

```
main(argc, argv)
a
b
c
```

Thanks!

Comment: I didn't see any `{` char in your input. It would be better if you post input and expected output.

Comment: Thanks, have done this!

Comment: Normally, I would use `[^{]*`. Not sure about sed.

Comment: Could you give an example of this please?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your reply. It could work like this: http://regex101.com/r/xD4aK9/1 regex: `main\s*\(\s*argc\s*,\s*argv\s*\)[^{]*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -n '/main(argc, argv)/,/{/ p'
```

On my system (Mac OS X), it does this:

```
$ sed -n '/main(argc, argv)/,/{/ p' t.txt
main(argc, argv)
a
b
c
<any other input, not including {>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this is doing, but it seems to just empty the input file.

Comment: What do you mean?  I'll add a full transcript of my running the command now.

Comment: Aha! Almost working, thanks.. But it matches the { character.

Comment: does not work is main and { are on the same line. Add maybe `/main(.*{/{p;b;}`